# ¿Guardar datos de función asincrona en variable global en JavaScript? Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estoy intentando obtener en la función `main` varios valores de altura, el problema es que los guardo en una variable y siempre muestra `undefined`. Necesito hacerlo así ya que quiero sacar una matriz con las alturas para una determinada zona.

```
   var resultado;
  function main(){


  var aux1=new google.maps.LatLng(39.5279017, -2.9419203);
  initialize(aux1,function(aux1){
    console.log(aux1); //Muestra la altura correctamente
    resultado = aux1;

   });



  console.log(resultado); //Muestra undefined
}


  function initialize(aux1,fn) {
     var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;

    // Initiate the location request
     elevator.getElevationForLocations({'locations': [location]
        }, function(results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
        // Retrieve the first result

             if (results[0]) {
           // console.log('altura del punto seleccionado '+results[0].elevation + ' meters.');
             fn(results[0].elevation);

           } else {
              console.log('No results found');
           }
       } else {
            console.log('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
        }


   });
 }
```

Comment: en qué momento ejecutas la función main?

Comment: es laprimera funcion que se ejecuta, lo que pasa que no he copiado el codigo html que la carga, fallo mio.

Comment: agrega el html y asunto solucionado :D

Answer (score 3):

> si yo hago window.resultado=results[0].elevation dentro de initialize y luego dentro del main muestro window.resultado me sigue mostrando undefined

`resultado` no ha sido inicializada, por lo que su valor es `undefined`.

El error es que **console.log(resultado);** debería estar dentro de la función (callback) que se pasa por parametro a **initialize**.

Ten en cuenta que **elevator.getElevationForLocations** realiza una llamada `ajax`, las funciones `callbacks` que resive no se ejecutan inmediatamente, pero todo lo que esta fuera si (la ejecución continua). Luego,  `transcurrido x cantidad de tiempo`, si todo anduvo bien, **fn(results[0].elevation);** es ejecutada y es inmediatamente después de esto que `resultado` dejara de valer `undefined`.

Una posible solución seria, ejecutar una funcion que te notifique que `resultado` ya tiene otro valor. Por ejemplo:

```
var resultado;

function hacerAlgoConResultado() {
  console.log(resultado);
}
function main(){
  var aux1=new google.maps.LatLng(39.5279017, -2.9419203);
  initialize(aux1,function(aux1){
    console.log(aux1); //Muestra la altura correctamente
    resultado = aux1;
    // En este punto ya tiene un valor
    hacerAlgoConResultado(); // Le avisamos que ahora ya si tenemos el resutaldo
  });
}
```

Te suguiero leer estos post: 
http://www.nauzethdez.com/js-9-programacion-asincrona/
http://www.nauzethdez.com/js-10-programacion-asincrona-ii/

Comment: Esta es de hecho la unica forma posible de usar un callback, excepto por usar Promises.

Comment: sigo dandole vueltas a esto...entonces de ninguna manera podría almacenarlo en la variable global? yo lo que quiero es tener ese dato y poder manipularlo desde cualquier función que tenga definida. No solo desde las llamadas dentro de initialize

Comment: Si miras con cuidado el script, veras que `resultado` es una variable global. Si deseas puedes escribirla `window.resultado` lo que es exactemente lo mismo, solo que es mas explicito.

Comment: si yo hago window.resultado=results[0].elevation dentro de initialize y luego dentro del main muestro window.resultado me sigue mostrando undefined

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Espero que esta vez haya sido mas claro :)